# How does one access the Node Type Constants in IE

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a node that I'm note sure is an element (from calling node.previousSibling). However I am having trouble finding out the cross browser javascript way to access the [Node constants](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node#Constants) shown on the [MDC](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Web_Development).

In all browsers but IE Node.ELEMENT_NODE is defined. I tried using a specific instance of node, e.g.:

```
e=$("#element_id")[0];
alert("ELEMENT_NODE: " + ELEMENT_NODE);
```

This does not work in IE either. So whats the IE way to do this? Do I just have to define the node constants myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 and earlier don't define the node type constants, so you would have to define them yourself.  Additionally, Internet Explorer 7 and earlier only [support types 1 and 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534191(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: MSDN may say `nodeType`'s values can only be 1 or 3, but it's not true. `document.nodeType` returns 9, for example, in IE 7. `document.createComment("foo").nodeType` returns 8.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to define the Node Constants [when they don't exist] is by catching the exception generated when attempting to access them.

```
try {
    if (Node.ELEMENT_NODE != 1) {
        throw true;
    }
}
catch(e) {
    document.Node = Node || {};
    Node.ELEMENT_NODE   = 1;
    Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE = 2;
    Node.TEXT_NODE      = 3;
}
```

The `throw true` line only executes when `Node` exists, but `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` is not the expected value.

Comment: This won't do what you said it does as long as `Node` is defined; `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` will just be undefined, and so the `throw true` line definitely does end up getting executed.

Comment: @Gijs That's incorrect. This code explicitly throws if `Node` is defined but `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` is not equal to `1`.

Comment: @Gijs My apologies, I didn't fully read your statement. You are correct. I've edited my answer to reflect the logic more closely.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(oNode.nodeType)
```

and you'll get:

```
"1" for ELEMENT_NODE  
"2" for ATTRIBUTE_NODE  
"3" for TEXT_NODE   
"4" for CDATA_SECTION_NODE  
"5" for ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE   
"6" for ENTITY_NODE
```

etc...