# TEXT_NODE in IE < 9 jQuery problems

Tags: jquery, textnode

I have this simple function to find "unwrapped" text and wrap it into a div.

It is working fine apart from IE < 9. What can I change here to make it working please.

> $('#categories_list')   .contents()   .filter(function() {
>       return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;   }).wrap("");

Many thanks in advance.

Dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node type constants aren't defined in IE, so in your code there `Node.TEXT_NODE` is undefined not `3` as it should be. Essentially, in IE < 9, your filter is asking `3 == undefined`, which obviously is false.

See: [How does one access the Node Type Constants in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444650/how-does-one-access-the-node-type-constants-in-ie) for workarounds.